# network old mac to use as rsync backup

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ssh, rsync

#### The goal:

Be able to run my rsync backup on my local machine "X" (Ubuntu 13.1) to a remote machine, a currently un-networked mac "Y" (OSX 10.2.8).

#### What I've done so far:

1. Flew to the old mac
2. Connected to the internet (wired to
   router)
3. Turned off firewall for remote login for ssh
4. Established port #
5. Set static IP 192.YYY.Y.Y
6. Reanmed machine "Y"
7. Connected local machine "X" to wifi
8. Connection test in linux terminal on "X":

   `ping Y.local`
   `ping: unknown host Y.local`
    
   `ping 192.YYY.Y.Y`
   `From 66.xx.xx.xx icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded`

#### What I need help with:

I would like to be able to first ssh into this old machine, then rsync into it.  I have the rsync part under control, its just this network issue I'm having difficulty troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you really use `198.X.X.X` as a static IP for your MAC? If so, then that's the whole problem: the static IP you assign to pcs inside a LAN should belong to the local LAN. In most cases, if you have not tampered with network settings, they are of the type 192.168.0.X, or 192.168.1.X, which are *private non-routable* addresses, while all addresses of the type 198.0.0.0/8 are *public routable* addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On Machine Y, you need to enable AFP and SSH (file sharing and remote login, under the "Sharing" tab)
2. for best options, you need to create a public key on X, and then copy it into the 'known_hosts' file on Machine Y.

to create the key on Mac:  https://docs.joyent.com/public-cloud/getting-started/ssh-keys/generating-an-ssh-key-manually/manually-generating-your-ssh-key-in-mac-os-x

this probably works on your linux box as well..

Then, copy that key INTO the .ssh/known_hosts file on the Mac

This will allow you to directly log in the Mac from your linux box, without requiring a username/password every time (the public key acts as your password)

Also, make sure you're doing the IP address properly..

ping 192.YY.YY.YYY

it should reply.

next try: ssh username@192.Y.YY.YYY    ('username' is one of the usernames on Y)
it should return iwth a password request...

once you're in, then VIM the .ssh/known_hosts file, and paste your public key into the end of it, then save ( to save, type ":wq")

at this point you should be able to 'exit', then when you 'ssh' into it again, it should not require a password...

after you've got this working, your rsync issue should be just fine...

Comment: @frank_ankersly your solution worked perfectly, thanks.  The problem was that I failed to enable AFP and SSH. I skipped the keygen step for troubleshooting, but I'll use it when before I start automating rsync.

Comment: The thing I always forget, after creating an ssh account to ssh or rsync into, and remote login, and do the rsa keys, and all that, when I think it should work, things don't.  Ans. Create a .bashrc and .bash_profile, without them, ssh commands are lost.  See a comment I made about these files some time ago on this site for clues as to their (~/.bashrc & ~/.bash_profile) construction.